# FrontEnd - Obfuscate classname in reactjs of MUI components

Tags: reactjs, hash, frontend, obfuscation, classname

I'm trying to find the way to hash classname of all the components that use mui in my project and can't seem to find the right way. I want output like facebook or google all classes are hashed. If the product uses css-module, it is possible to add a plugin in the webpack for hashing, but here I am using regular css and mui component. Does anyone have relevant documentation or specific instructions? As if using jss to do for example? Thanks.

I tried using the **classNameGenerator** provided by mui but it only changed part of the class to some numbered characters after it. what i want is all classnames with no rules.